# How to derive: F(xy)→∼F(yx) ∴ ∼F(xx)

Tags: logic

This is from Logic 2010, Derivation 4.021: F(xy)→∼F(yx) ∴ ∼F(xx). The book we use is Parsons', but I cannot even make sense of these symbols stand-alone F(xx) without any quantifier. This problem appears in the exercises for the chapter on quantifier, but I did not find any instance of these kinds of derivations in Parsons' book. Could someone kindly help me out with this?

Comment: See [Asymmetric relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_relation) : an asymmetric relation must be [irreflexive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation#Related_terms).

Comment: There is somewhere in the book some point where it is explained how to handle open formulae: i.e. **Pxy** must be considerd universally quantified.

Answer (score 1):

Get yourself a copy of Logic: Techniques of Formal Reasoning, by Kalish, Montague, & Mar.

Here is a link: [https://www.amazon.com/Logic-Techniques-Reasoning-Donald-Kalish/dp/0195155041](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0195155041)

Show   ∼F(xx)

1        F(xx)                ASS ID (Assume Indirect Derivation)

2        F(xy)→∼F(yx)         PR (Premise)

**Remember to EI (Existential Instantiation) before you UI (Universal Instantiation) and UI what you EI to!**

3       Ej((Fxj)->~F(jx))    EG/j (Existential Generalization) Line 2

4       F(xi)->~F(ix)        EI/i (Existential Instantiation) Line 3

5       \forall k (F(xk)->~F(kx))  UG/k (Universal Generalization) Line 4

6       F(xx)->~F(xx)        UI/k->x  (Universal Instantiation) Line 5

7       ~F(xx)               MP (Modus Ponens) Lines 1 & 6

8       QED                  Indirect Derivation, Lines 1 & 7

What this means: If there is some x that stands in some relationship F to y, then it's not the case that y stands in relationship F to x...   so for this problem let's think about F as 'loves'...

If x loves y --> y does not love x. Therefore it's not the case that x loves itself. Re-walk yourself through the derivation thinking about F as love and hopefully it'll make a bit more sense!

Let me know if you need any more help! I've done almost every problem in that book!

Comment: I'm not sure that it works that way ... see page 101 regarding **UI** : "the variable *alpha*, called the variable of generalization, must not be free in any antecedent line." Compare your lines 4 and 5...

Comment: The exercise is n°78 (page 175) of Kalish & Montague; frankly speaking, I cannot find in the book other similar examples with free variables ... If not "properly" quantified, the formula is *invalid*; consider as **F** the binary predicate **≤** between natural numbers : **(1≤0) → ∼(0≤1)** is *true* while **∼(1≤1)** is *false*.

Comment: You are definitely right about my inappropriate and lazy usage of Universal Generalization, the variable must not exist free in a preceding line. But, I'm going to edit it to a new variable and you will see that the proof works! Great catch! Editing the variable of generalization to k!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one (possibly not 100% correct but hopefully intuitive) way to think about it: A formula with a free variable, like Fx, is like saying "that thing is F", where the thing being indicated is left unspecified.  So, it could be true or false, depending on which object serves as the value of x (i.e., what "that thing" is).

When you're given a formula containing a free variable, like Fx, as a premise, it's like being told that "that thing is F" is true, and if that's true, no matter what "that thing" (i.e., the value of x) is, then it must be the case that everything is F.  (If, no matter what I'm pointing at, the formula "that thing is friendly" is true, then it must be that everything is friendly.)

Terminology: Call a formula containing at least one free variable an "open formula." Suppose you take the open formula Fx, which has a free x, and bind the free x to a universal quantifier occurring in front of the formula, so that you have AxFx (that 'A' is supposed to be upside down, i.e., it's supposed to be read, "for all x Fx".  I just can't make a universal quantifier symbol here).  Then we say that AxFx is the *universal closure* of Fx.  Similarly, if you have two free variables in a formula, like

Fx->Gy

then the universal closure would be

AxAy(Fx->Gy)

In general, the universal closure of an open formula is the result of binding each of the free variable occurrences in the original open formula to a universal quantifier occurring at the front of the formula.

Logic 2010 doesn't contain a Universal Generalization rule.  But it does contain a system for completing Universal Derivations.  Whenever you have a premise that, like Fx, is an open formula, I recommend you start by deriving its universal closure on line 1.  This will be easy.  After completing that derivation, only *then* show conc and continue the proof, but now use the newly-derived universal closure of the premise instead of the premise.  Like so:
[image: Logic 2010 4.021]

From here just ASS ID as usual and continue the proof.  You'll see that if you UI line 1 twice to x the problem is trivial.

Note that this isn't always the quickest or most elegant approach.  But hopefully it makes sense intuitively.  And it works for lots of other problems where one or more premise contains free variables, like 4.022, 3.031, and 3.031, among others.